# Recognize specific lexemes using Lex ignoring the rest of the code

Tags: compiler-construction, lex, lexical-analysis

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
   printf("\n Hello world");
}
```

In the above code, how can i make the lexical analyzer to recognize only **main( )** and ignore rest of the code such that the output displays only **main( )** and its line number.

(*Without adding too many cases, in case of a lengthy code*)

Answer (score 1):

If you want an accurate result, you need to properly recognize most tokens. Consider the following snippets:

```
/*
   int main()
 */
```

Or

```
 const char* header = "\
 int main()   \
 ";
```

If you don't care about accuracy, (f)lex is probably overkill. You could just use `strstr` or, for a little more flexibility, the posix regex library.